# Display the data only when the submit button is clicked?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC.when I execute the mvc Search the data is automatically displaying.When I enter into search box then corresponding row is dispalying.But how can I write code such that when I execute it should be with only search button and when click on it the data should appear.How?

```
public ActionResult Search(int? myid)
{             
    var s = from sp in db.Vedios
            select sp;

    if (myid.HasValue)        
    {
        s = s.Where(st=>st.id==myid);
    }

    return View(s.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Could you add your view codes. Your explaining is a bit confusing. Can you write more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your query that return data. Your query seems to return all the data if no search parameter specified. Also, I suggest that you check the get method of your controller, remove the code that fetch the data from get method and put it into post.

It would be helpful if you post the query here.

public ActionResult Search(int? myid)
       {

```
    var s = new List<Vedio>();
    if (myid.HasValue)

    {
        s = db.Vedios.Where(st=>st.id==myid);
    }

    return View(s.ToList());
```

}